# Google Spreadsheet Translate, ignore variable names

Tags: google-sheets

An interesting Google Spreadsheet problem, I have a language file based on key=value that I have copied into a spreadsheet, eg.

```
titleMessage=Welcome to My Website
youAreLoggedIn=Hello #{user.name} you are now logged in
facebookPublish=Facebook Publishing
```

I have managed to split the key / value into two columns, and then translate the value column, and re-join it with the keys and Voila! this gives me a translated language file back

But as you may have spotted there are some variable in there (eg. #{user.name}) which are injected by my application, obviously I dont want to translate them.

So here is my question, given the following cell contents...

```
Hello #{user.name} you are now logged in
```

Is there a function that will translate the contents using the TRANSLATE function, but ignore anything inside #{ } (this could be at any point in the sentance)

Any Google Spreadsheet guru's have a solution for me?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there are at most one occurrence of #{} then you could use the SPLIT function to divide the string into three parts that are arranged as below.

```
A           B                   C                 D           E
Original    =SPLIT(An, "#{}")   First piece       Tag         Rest of string
                                Translate         Keep as is  Translate
```

Put the pieces together with CONCATENATE.

```
=CONCATINATE(Cn,Dn,En)
```

Answer (score 0):

I come up with same question.

Assume the escape pattern is `#{sth.sth}`(in regex as `#{[\w.]+}`). Replace them with string which Google Translate would view as untranslatable term, like `VAR`.

After translation, replace the term with original pattern.

Here is how I did this in script editor of spreadsheet:

```js
function myTranslate(text, source_language, target_language) {
  if(text.toString()) {
    var str = text.toString();
    var regex = /#{[\w.]+}/g; // g flag for multiple matches
    var replace = 'VAR'; // Replace #{variable} to prevent from translation
    var vars = str.match(regex).reverse(); // original patterns
    str = str.replace(regex, replace);

    str = LanguageApp.translate(str, source_language, target_language);

    var ret = '';
    for (var idx = str.search(replace); idx; idx = str.search(replace)) {
      ret += str.slice(0, idx) + vars.pop();
      str = str.slice(idx+replace.length);
    }
    return ret;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just split and concatenate, because different languages use different word order of subject/predicate/object etc., and also because several languages modify nouns with different prefixes/suffixes/spelling changes depending on what they are doing in the sentence. It's all very complicated. Google needs to enable some sort of enclosing parentheses around any term we want to be quoted rather than translated.